# How to run Get-ChildItem command on a remote machine

Tags: powershell

I need to run the following:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse
```

on a remote machine. For instance I have a loop:

```
foreach ($server in $serverList) {
   if((Test-Connection -Cn $server -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
   {
        $certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse | Select Thumbnail, subject
        .....
   }
}
```

How can I ensure it runs on the remote machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Invoke-Command`:

```
foreach ($server in $serverList) {
   if((Test-Connection -Cn $server -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
   {
        $certs = Invoke-Command -Cn $server {
            Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse | Select Thumbnail, subject
        }
        .....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using invoke-command, and variables, variable are set in global Context of where the command is executed. you then need to tell to the invoke-command to use a global variable, instead of the other end computer variable that don't exit

```
$Using:
```

example:

```
$RemoteComputerLocalPath = "C:\TEMP\"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$computerName" -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem 
$Using:RemoteComputerLocalPath}
```